# `git pull` locks up on one repository

Tags: git

I have a remote git server that has been working great for months.  Earlier today a couple of my teammates said they were having trouble with `git pull` for one of our projects.

I am testing it now and I cannot preform a `git pull` either.  I was able to run `git fetch` once, but now that isn't working.  When I look at the server processes for the git user (the one that connects to the remote repo) I see 3 processes that are just sitting there: `sshd`, `php`, and `git-upload-pack`.

All of the other repositories that are also on this remote server are working fine.  The repository is fairly large and just had a new branch added to it.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a wild guess, check the file permissions.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  It belongs elsewhere.  When you ask in an appropriate forum, be sure to add more detail, e.g. did you get an error message, or is it just still running?

 If you're not using command-line git, then do that so you will see any error messages or passwordless-ssh problems.

Comment: What hooks are enabled on that repository? Do you have any explanation for the php process?

Comment: Yes. The php process is a hook.  It is part of a larger application for publishing our changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being an issue with remote repositories over ssh for that one project.  To fix it I rebuilt the remote repository by following these steps on the remote server.

1.In a temp location run`git clone /full/path/to/local/repo/project.git temp_repo`, then `cd temp_repo`

2.Make sure you `create`, `checkout`, and `pull` every branch (I had 3).

3.Now you have a complete fresh copy of the repository, just overwrite the original with the new one with `mv /path/to/new/temp_repo /full/path/to/local/repo`

Answer (score 1):

git-fsck and git-gc

Comment: Now that's what I call a verbose answer.